# Django models relationship tests

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-testing

I am new to django testing and have some issues using them to test relationship between models.

Here is an extract of my models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    points = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.points

    def get_number_of_poll(self):
        nbr_of_poll = Poll.objects.filter(user=self.user).count()
        return nbr_of_poll

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

And here are the tests:

```
from polls.models import Member, Poll
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase

class MemberTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User(username='user')
        self.member = Member(user=user, points=5000)
        poll = Poll(question='poll', user=user)

    def test_get_number_of_poll(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.member.get_number_of_poll(), 1)
```

The issue is with the `test_get_number_of_poll()` method that always returns 0. The code works as expected on the site. 
Am I doing something wrong with the test? I am not sure how I am supposed to set the poll in the test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
poll = Poll(question='poll', user=user)
```

Only instantiates the Poll object, use the manager to actually save the object, e.g.

```
poll = Poll.objects.create(question='poll', user=user)
```

Comment: That makes sense. And once the tests are done, am I supposed to use the `tearDown()` method to remove them or it's done automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You don't save any of the items you create in your setUp method. Instantiating a model object doesn't save it to the database: you should either call `save()` on them, or just use `User.objects.create(username='user')` etc which does the save for you.